# How to fix the position of QGraphicsItem and making only the QGraphicsTextItem to move?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicstextitem

I have a `QGraphicsView` in which I am painting a `QGraphicsItem` and `QGraphicsTextItem`.

I have set the flag `ItemIsMovable` for the `QGraphicsTextItem` for editing the long text.

Here my concern. When I am moving the `QGraphicsTextItem` to view the long text, it is also moving the `QGraphicsText` to left.

But I want only the `QGraphicsTextItem` to be movable.

I want to fix the position of `QGraphicsItem`? How do I do that?

Edit: [image]
Here is the output of my code. I have this `QGraphicsView` at the top-left of my application. The Viewport of this `QGraphicsView` is the width of the `QGraphicsItem`.

When I click on the `QGraphicsTextItem` and move the cursor to the right to view the text, the `QGraphicsItem` also moves and becomes hidden as shown in the image.

How do I fix the position of this `QGraphicsItem`?

Comment: Please include a minimal code example which reproduces the problem in your question so we can see what exactly you are doing

Comment: There is no such item as a QGraphicsText, please edit the question to clarify what you mean.